# Spring Boot 2 + JdbcTemplate - is there a way to provide SQL query for each database supported?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I'm working on a Spring Boot 2.4.2 based project and using "*spring-boot-starter-jdbc*" and "*com.oracle.database.jdbc*" for Oracle Jdbc driver.

As I use **JdbcTemplate** to interact with DB, everything seems clean and easy. But I may need to support multiple database types in future - Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, DB2, etc.
Did quite a bit of Googling but did not find any option for this..

Like mentioned above, I am using **Spring-Jdbc** (not *Spring Data JDBC* or *Spring Data JPA*) - how do I provide the SQL queries specific to each database supported in the code or configuration?

Please, let me know your thoughts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Spring JDBC, but you could user Spring dependency injection mechanism to create a profile for each database.

First an interface:

```
public interface DbQueries {
    String createQueryForSelectingUsers();
}
```

Then implement the interface for each supported database:

```
@Profile("mysql")
@Component
public class MySqlDbQueries implements DbQueries {

    @Override
    public String createQueryForSelectingUsers() {
        return "SELECT * FROM USER";
    }
}
```

2nd example:

```
@Profile("oracle")
@Component
public class OracleDbQueries implements DbQueries {

    @Override
    public String createQueryForSelectingUsers() {
        return "SELECT * FROM USER";
    }
}
```

Afterwards use it where you need it:

```
public class MyRepository {

    private DbQueries dbQueries;

    // DbQueries implementation will be injected based on your current profile
    public MyRepository(DbQueries dbQueries) {
        this.dbQueries = dbQueries;
    }

    public void printAllUsers() {

        String query = dbQueries.createQueryForSelectingUsers();

        // stuff to execute query
    }
}
```

Remember to start your app with a profile with e.q. `--spring.profiles.active=mysql` or adding active profile information into `application.properties`:

```
spring.profiles.active=mysql
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin. I did not think of using Profiles, because I'd plan to place application.properties containing DB details in the same folder as the Spring Boot jar.

With profiles, users need to pass the profile name additionally,  even after specifying their database details in an external application.properties file.

Comment: You can apply the active profile in application.properties by adding one line: spring.profiles.active=mysql

Comment: Maybe I will have to set profile value programmatically in the Spring Boot's main class, the one with @SpringBootApplication - based on the driver class set in the application,properties. So at least this way users need not set the profile manually.

I will accept this is as an answer if there is nothing inbuilt offered by Spring Boot or unless someone suggest something better. Thank you.